# When I try to import PySTAF i get the following error. I am using a 32bit STAF for 32bit PYTHON

Tags: python, dll, staf

```
C:\STAF32\bin>python PySTAF.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PySTAF.py", line 9, in <module>
import PYSTAF
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Environment variable points to C:\STAF32\bin; 
Pythonpath = C:\STAF\bin\

Pycharm environment vairble = PYTHONCASEOK=

Stuck on this one for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually add the path to the PySTAF module to the system path.
STAF installation doesn't take care of this one automatically.
If you are on windows, create a new Env Variable: ***PYTHONPATH*** = "C:\STAF\bin" (location to PySTAF.py module in your installation)